# Issue with Cert-manager ClusterIssuer in AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, cert-manager

I am getting this error in clusterissuer (cert-manager version 1.7.1):

"Error getting keypair for CA issuer: error decoding certificate PEM block"

I have the ca.crt, tls.crt and tls.key stored in a Key Vault in Azure.

**kubectl describe clusterissuer ca-issuer**

```
  Ca:
    Secret Name:  cert-manager-secret
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2022-02-25T11:40:49Z
    Message:               Error getting keypair for CA issuer: error decoding certificate PEM block
    Observed Generation:   1
    Reason:                ErrGetKeyPair
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
Events:
  Type     Reason         Age                  From          Message
  ----     ------         ----                 ----          -------
  Warning  ErrGetKeyPair  3m1s (x17 over 58m)  cert-manager  Error getting keypair for CA issuer: error decoding certificate PEM block
  Warning  ErrInitIssuer  3m1s (x17 over 58m)  cert-manager  Error initializing issuer: error decoding certificate PEM block
```

**kubectl get clusterissuer**

```
NAME        READY   AGE
ca-issuer   False   69m
```

- This is the clusterissuer yaml file:

**ca-issuer.yaml**

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: ca-issuer
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  ca:
    secretName: cert-manager-secret
```

This is the KeyVault yaml file to retrieve the ca.crt, tls.crt and tls.key

**keyvauls.yaml**

```
apiVersion: spv.no/v2beta1
kind: AzureKeyVaultSecret
metadata:
  name: secret-akscacrt
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  vault:
    name: kv-xx # name of key vault
    object:
      name: akscacrt # name of the akv object
      type: secret # akv object type
  output: 
    secret: 
      name: cert-manager-secret # kubernetes secret name
      dataKey: ca.crt # key to store object value in kubernetes secret
---
apiVersion: spv.no/v2beta1
kind: AzureKeyVaultSecret
metadata:
  name: secret-akstlscrt
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  vault:
    name: kv-xx # name of key vault
    object:
      name: akstlscrt # name of the akv object
      type: secret # akv object type
  output: 
    secret: 
      name: cert-manager-secret # kubernetes secret name
      dataKey: tls.crt # key to store object value in kubernetes secret
---
apiVersion: spv.no/v2beta1
kind: AzureKeyVaultSecret
metadata:
  name: secret-akstlskey
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  vault:
    name: kv-xx # name of key vault
    object:
      name: akstlskey # name of the akv object
      type: secret # akv object type
  output: 
    secret: 
      name: cert-manager-secret # kubernetes secret name
      dataKey: tls.key # key to store object value in kubernetes secret
---
```

and these are the certificates used:

```
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: argocd-xx
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  secretName: argocd-xx
  issuerRef:
    name: ca-issuer
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: "argocd.xx"
  dnsNames:
    - "argocd.xx"
  privateKey:
    size: 4096
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: sonarqube-xx
  namespace: sonarqube
spec:
  secretName: "sonarqube-xx"
  issuerRef:
    name: ca-issuer
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: "sonarqube.xx"
  dnsNames:
    - "sonarqube.xx"
  privateKey:
    size: 4096
```

I can see that I can retrive the secrets for the certificate from key vault:

**kubectl get secret -n cert-manager cert-manager-secret -o yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  ca.crt: XXX
  tls.crt: XXX
  tls.key: XXX
```

Also, another strange thing is that I am getting other secrets in sonarqube/argocd namespace  which I deployed previously but are not any more in my deployment file. I cannot delete them, when I try to delete them, they are re-created automatically. Looks like they are stored in some kind of cache. Also I tried to delete the namespace akv2k8s/cert-manager and delete the cert-manager/akv2k8s controllers and re-install them again but same issue after re-installing and applying the deployment...

```
kubectl get secret -n sonarqube

NAME                                      TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
cert-manager-secret                       Opaque                                3      155m
default-token-c8b86                       kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      2d1h
sonarqube-xx-7v7dh   Opaque                                1      107m
sql-db-secret                             Opaque                                2      170m

kubectl get secret -n argocd   
NAME                                   TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
argocd-xx-7b5kb   Opaque                                1      107m
cert-manager-secret-argo               Opaque                                3      157m
default-token-pjb4z                    kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      3d15h
```

**kubectl describe certificate sonarqube-xxx -n sonarqube**

```
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:        2022-02-25T11:04:08Z
    Message:                     Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
    Observed Generation:         1
    Reason:                      DoesNotExist
    Status:                      False
    Type:                        Ready
    Last Transition Time:        2022-02-25T11:04:08Z
    Message:                     Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
    Observed Generation:         1
    Reason:                      DoesNotExist
    Status:                      True
    Type:                        Issuing
  Next Private Key Secret Name:  sonarqube-xxx-7v7dh
Events:                          <none>
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Which `cert-manager` version is used? there was an [issue](https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/issues/4142) with similar error in `1.4.0`. As for certificates, try to kubectl get ... -o yaml` and see if there are any parents/mentions.

Comment: I'm using 1.7.1. If you mean 'kubectl get secret -n cert-manager cert-manager-secret -o yaml' yes cert info is there.

Comment: Did it work previously? Or is this an initial installation? There's a chance something is not correct with certificates stored in Azure vault. As for the certificate, yes, it will be there, but you need to figure out if there are any `metadata.ownerReferences:` which can be the reason why it gets recreated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out just uploading the certificate info **ca.crt**. **tls.crt** and **tls.key** **in plain text, without BASE64 encoding** in the Key Vault secrets in Azure.

When AKV2K8S retrives the secrets from the Key Vault and stored in Kubernetes, automatically it is encoded in BASE64.

Regards,

Comment: Azure KeyVault only supports single line values, did you copy the output and then convert it to a single line? I tried your solution and I still receive the same error

Comment: The solution was to create the secret via Azure CLI since this supported multi line values